# Is there a way to turn a jar file into an executable (on windows) that can run independently?

Tags: java

I've tried GCJ but that was giving me problems and it's apparently not supported anymore, so what can I use? I don't want something that just wraps the jar file, but something that actually recompiles it into an independent exe. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is!

> Using GraalVM Java applications can be compiled into native standalone executables (will be demonstrated).

Check this site : https://technology.amis.nl/2018/08/21/java-programs-as-native-executables-graalvm-is-the-answer/

Comment: I literally specifically said I did not want a wrapper

Comment: Do your part of the work.  Graalvm can compile to native code.